# Overlay div won't display on Safari (webkit)

Tags: html, css, safari, sass, webkit

I have a div that I want to center on top of an opaque image that covers the screen. I have gotten it to work fine in Chrome (blink), but I cannot get it to show up in Safari (webkit). I've created a [simplified JSFiddle version of my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/jakepeyser/qpevk7vz/) and included the code snippets here as well.

**HTML**

```
<div id="home">
  <div class="wallpaper"></div>
  <div class="info-wrapper">
    <span class="name">John Doe</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
#home {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.wallpaper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: inherit;
  opacity: .5;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440700265116-fe3f91810d72);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.info-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  > .name {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 7em;
  }
}
```

I am open to changing the structure of my HTML if that makes solving this issue easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update]

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed'

You can get more details in this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.red {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

In this sample, the green box without setting `left` property, the value should be `auto`, and result should be refer to the nearest element. And, that shows correct in Safari and Firefox. Chrome is no up to the standard.

---

[Older]

I think what you need is let the wallpaper out of the document flow. Run the sample in safari. [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qpevk7vz/5/)

```
.wallpaper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: inherit;
    opacity: .5;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440700265116-    fe3f91810d72);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That solved the overlay issue, thanks! Now to figure out the vertical centering problem, but that's for another post if necessary